# Setting up a 3M Serial Touchscreen

Tags: drivers, 10.04, touchscreen, multi-touch

I've been attempting for quite a long time to get a Serial 3M Touchscreen to work on Ubuntu 10.04.

The closest post I could find to what I needed was this one:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1508944&highlight=3m+touchscreen

Unfortunately, I get to where I touch the screen and the mouse jumps to the top right corner and that is it.  The calibration software doesn't really work (straight from 3M).  Either sometimes it won't start, or there is something wrong with it.

It now looks like the problem has to do with the calibration software not recognizing the attached touchscreen.  With some changes to the installation script, I was able to get the calibration software to install properly.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright 2007-2009 3M. All rights reserved.
#
# This script installs the MT7 touch screen driver
# During installation, all directories must be writeable.
#

# These symbols point to where the MT7 software binaries and data reside.
# The script attempts to detect where the installation kit is. If this
# fails, you need to set BinDir.
# The data directory must be on writeable media. The script normally uses
# the directory where the installation kit resides as the data directory.
# If you need the data directory to be elsewhere, set DataDir.
BinDir=""
DataDir=""

# If desired, define a file to contain driver startup options and set
# the TwDrv_Cfg symbol to the full path of the file. Normally this is
# not needed.
TwDrv_Cfg=""

# This symbol points to where the Java VM binaries reside.
JavaBinDir=""

# These symobls point to system and applictaion directories other than
# those specific to the MT7 software
UdevDir="/etc/udev"
HotplugDir="/etc/hotplug"
XorgDir="/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input"
XFree86Dir="/usr/X11R6/lib/modules/input"
LibDir="/usr/lib"
SEDir1="/usr/selinux/booleans"
SEDir2="/selinux/booleans"
LSBDir="/lib/lsb"

# The InitDir symbol points to where this script places an 'init' script.
# If left blank, this script first looks for /etc/init.d and then /etc/rc.d.
# If this is not appropriate or this script otherwise fails, set this value.
InitDir=""

# This symbol enables permission for some MT7 shared objects on
# SELinux systems. On most systems SEGivePermission is texrel_shlib_t.
# Change this variable if another security type is appropriate.
SEGivePermission="texrel_shlib_t"

# This symbol affects when the X input driver converts raw touch screen
# coordinates into screen coordiates. Normally, the X input driver reports
# the raw coordinates to the X server which then calls an conversion
# routine. Some versions of the X server expect the initial report to
# contain converted coordinates. If your touch behavior is off and
# calibration does not address the problem, set ConvertAtRead to true.
ConvertAtRead="false"

# This symbol defines the name of the xorg.conf file to generate if one is
# not found. Starting with X server version 1.5, this file is not
# automatically generated. This file is needed for MT 7 for Linux to work.
# If you want the file to reside elsewhere, set this symbol.
XorgConf="/etc/X11/xorg.conf"

# These symbols define where the 50MT7-xinit script needs to go and what
# suffix it requires. The script places this file automatically in
# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d and /etc/X11/Xsession.d without a suffix. If
# your distribution requires another location or requires a suffix on the
# file, set these symbols.
XinitDir=""
XinitSuffix=""

# Determine the installation directory
if [ -z $BinDir ]
then
   if [ $(echo $0 | grep ^/) ]
   then
      BinDir=$0
   else
      BinDir=$(echo $PWD"/"$0 | sed s#[.]/##)
   fi
   BinDir=$(echo $BinDir | sed s%/[^/]*$%%)
fi

# Determine if the system is compatible
$BinDir/TwCompat
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
   echo "ERROR: MT7 for Linux not installed - shared memory support not detected"
   exit
fi

# Determine the data directory
[ -z $DataDir ] && DataDir=$BinDir

# Create the data and fifo directories
if [ $DataDir != $BinDir ]
then
   [ -e $DataDir ] || mkdir $DataDir
   chmod a+w $DataDir
   ln -s $DataDir $BinDir/data
else
   [ -e $BinDir/data ] || mkdir $BinDir/data
fi
chmod a+w $BinDir/data
[ -e $BinDir/data/fifo ] || mkdir $BinDir/data/fifo
chmod a+w $BinDir/data/fifo

# Determine the init script directories
if [ -z $InitDir ] && [ -d /etc/init.d ]
then
   if [ $(ls -l /etc/init.d/ | sed -e /functions/d -e /^total\ [0-9]*$/d | wc -l) != 0 ]
   then
      InitDir="/etc/init.d"
   fi
fi
if [ -z $InitDir ]
then
   if [ -e /etc/rc.d/rc.local ]
   then
      InitDir=/etc/rc.d
   else
      InitDir=$BinDir
   fi
fi

# Install the init script
[ -e $InitDir/TWDrvStartup ] && rm -f $InitDir/TWDrvStartup
sed -e s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir#g \
    -e s#%INITDIR%#$InitDir#g \
    -e s#%LSBDIR%#$LSBDir#g \
    -e s#%TWDRV_CFG%#$TwDrv_Cfg#g $BinDir/TWDrvStartup.ORIG \
    >$InitDir/TWDrvStartup
chmod a+x $InitDir/TWDrvStartup
if perl $BinDir/TwIsThere.perl chkconfig
then
   chkconfig --add TWDrvStartup >/dev/null
elif perl $BinDir/TwIsThere.perl update-rc.d
then
   update-rc.d TWDrvStartup defaults >/dev/null
elif [ -e $InitDir/rc.local ]
then
   sed -e '$ a\
%INITDIR%/TWDrvStartup start
' $InitDir/rc.local >$InitDir/rc.local.TEMP
   rm -f $InitDir/rc.local
   sed -e s#%INITDIR%#$InitDir# $InitDir/rc.local.TEMP >$InitDir/rc.local
   rm -f $InitDir/rc.local.TEMP
   chmod +x $InitDir/rc.local
else
   echo "Cannot install the init script"
fi

# Test for USB support
if [ -z $(uname -r | grep ^2\.4\.) ]
then
   # Copy the udev rules script
   Hotplug=0
   if [ -d $UdevDir/rules.d ]
   then
      if [ -e $UdevDir/rules.d/99-TwDriver.rules ]
      then
         rm -f $UdevDir/rules.d/99-TwDriver.rules
      fi
      sed s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir#g $BinDir/99-TwDriver.rules.ORIG \
         >$UdevDir/rules.d/99-TwDriver.rules
      Hotplug=1
   fi
   if [ -d $HotplugDir/usb ] && [ -e $HotplugDir/usb.agent ]d
   then
      [ -e $HotplugDir/usb/TwHotplug ] && rm -f $HotplugDir/usb/TwHotplug
      sed s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir#g $BinDir/TwHotplug.ORIG > $HotplugDir/usb/TwHotplug
      chmod a+x $HotplugDir/usb/TwHotplug
      [ -e $HotplugDir/usb.usermap ] || echo "# Created by MT7" >$HotplugDir/usb.usermap
      sed <$HotplugDir/usb.usermap >$HotplugDir/usb.usermap.TEMP '$ a\
# TwHotplug is for the MT7 for Linux software\
TwHotplug            0x0001      0x0596   0x0000    0x0000       0x0000      0x00         0x00            0x00            0x06            0x00               0x00               0x00000000
'
      rm -f $HotplugDir/usb.usermap
      mv $HotplugDir/usb.usermap.TEMP $HotplugDir/usb.usermap
      Hotplug=1
   fi
   if [ $Hotplug == 0 ]
   then
      echo "Hotplugging of USB touch screen controllers is not supported"
   fi
else
   echo "USB touch screen controllers are not supported under kernel 2.4"
fi

# Test for the version of C++ standard libraries
if [ -e $LibDir/libstdc++.so.6 ]
then
   CppExt="6"
elif [ -e $LibDir/libstdc++.so.5 ]
then
   CppExt="5"
else
   echo "Cannot find needed libstdc++.so in $LibDir"
   CppExt=""
fi

# Link the libraries into /usr/lib
perl $BinDir/TwLibInstall.perl install $LibDir $BinDir/lib*.so
if [ x$CppExt != x ]
then
   perl $BinDir/TwLibInstall.perl install $LibDir $BinDir/so$CppExt/lib*.so
fi

# Link RnR sensitive files
if [ x$CppExt != x ]
then
   $BinDir/TwLibTest $LibDir/libTwSystemRnR12.so
   if [ x$? != x0 ]
   then
      rm -f $LibDir/libTwSystem.so
      ln -s $LibDir/libTwSystemRnR12.so $LibDir/libTwSystem.so
      ln -s $BinDir/TwMonitorRnR.bin$CppExt $BinDir/TwMonitor
   else
      $BinDir/TwLibTest $LibDir/libTwSystemRnR.so
      if [ x$? != x0 ]
      then
         rm -f $LibDir/libTwSystem.so
         ln -s $LibDir/libTwSystemRnR.so $LibDir/libTwSystem.so
         ln -s $BinDir/TwMonitorRnR.bin$CppExt $BinDir/TwMonitor
      else
         ln -s $BinDir/TwMonitor.bin$CppExt $BinDir/TwMonitor
      fi
   fi
fi

# Copy the X input driver
XCopyDefault=0
if [ -d $XorgDir ]
then
   XDir=$XorgDir
   if [ -z "$(X -version 2>&1 | grep X\.Org[^1]*1\.[4-9]\.)" ]
   then
      XSrc=$BinDir/twxinput_drv.so
   elif [ -z "$(X -version 2>&1 | grep X\.Org[^1]*1\.[5-9]\.)" ]
   then
      XSrc=$BinDir/twxinput_drv.so.1.4
   else
      XSrc=$BinDir/twxinput_drv.so.1.5.1
      XCopyDefault=1
   fi
elif [ -d $XFree86Dir ]
then
   XDir=$XFree86Dir
   XSrc=$BinDir/twxinput_drv.so
else
   XDir=""
   echo "Cannot install the X input module"
fi
if [ -d $XDir ]
then
   [ -e $XDir/twxinput_drv.o ] && rm -f $XDir/twxinput_drv.o
   [ -e $XDir/twxinput_drv.so ] && rm -f $XDir/twxinput_drv.so
   ln -s $XSrc $XDir/twxinput_drv.so
fi

# Install the xinit scripts
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]
then
   sed s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir#g $BinDir/50MT7-xinit.ORIG \
      >/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50MT7-xinit$XinitSuffix
   chmod a+x /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50MT7-xinit$XinitSuffix
fi
if [ -d /etc/X11/Xsession.d ]
then
   sed s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir#g $BinDir/50MT7-xinit.ORIG \
      >/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50MT7-xinit$XinitSuffix
   chmod a+x /etc/X11/Xsession.d/50MT7-xinit$XinitSuffix
fi
if [ x$XinitDir != x ]
then
   sed s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir#g $BinDir/50MT7-xinit.ORIG \
      >$XinitDir/50MT7-xinit$XinitSuffix
   chmod a+x $XinitDir/50MT7-xinit$XinitSuffix
fi

# Set up the SELinux security types
if [ -d $SEDir1 ]
then
   SEDir=$SEDir1
elif [ -d $SEDir2 ]
then
   SEDir=$SEDir2
else
   SEDir=""
fi
if [ x$SEDir != x ]
then
   chcon -t $SEGivePermission $LibDir/libTwSystem.so
   chcon -t $SEGivePermission $LibDir/libTwConfig.so
   chcon -t $SEGivePermission $LibDir/libTwIO_Utilities.so
   chcon -t $SEGivePermission $LibDir/libTwAppIO_JNI.so
   chcon -t $SEGivePermission $LibDir/libTwCommon_JNI.so
   chcon -t $SEGivePermission $LibDir/libTwConfig_JNI.so
   chcon -t $SEGivePermission $LibDir/libTwUI_JNI.so
   chcon -t $SEGivePermission $LibDir/libTwUICP.so
   [ -e $XDir/twxinput_drv.so ] && chcon -t $SEGivePermission $XDir/twxinput_drv.so
fi

# Set up the configuration
[ -d /dev/shm ] && rm -f /dev/shm/*TwConfig*
sed s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir#g $BinDir/TwFramework.cfg.ORIG >$BinDir/TwFramework.cfg
$BinDir/TwCfgUtil /u $BinDir/TwFramework.cfg
$BinDir/TwCfgUtil /u $BinDir/TwFactory.cfg

# Produce the Remove script
sed -e s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir#g \
    -e s#%UDEVDIR%#$UdevDir#g \
    -e s#%XDIR%#$XDir#g \
    -e s#%LIBDIR%#$LibDir#g \
    -e s#%SEDIR%#$SEDir#g \
    -e s#%HOTPLUGDIR%#$HotplugDir#g \
    -e s#%INITDIR%#$InitDir#g \
    -e s#%XINITDIR%#$XinitDir#g \
    -e s#%XINITSUFFIX%#$XinitSuffix#g \
    $BinDir/Remove.ORIG >$BinDir/Remove

# Produce the X input script
sed -e s#%CONVERT%#$ConvertAtRead#g \
    $BinDir/TWXinputInstall.perl.ORIG >$BinDir/TWXinputInstall.perl

# Produce the CP start script
sed -e s#%JAVABINDIR%#$JavaBinDir#g \
    -e s#%BINDIR%#$BinDir# \
    $BinDir/StartCP.ORIG >$BinDir/StartCP

# Set any necessary permissions
chmod a+x $BinDir/TwCalib
chmod a+x $BinDir/TWXinputInstall.perl
chmod u+x $BinDir/Remove
chmod a+x $BinDir/StartCP

# Copy the default xorg.conf
if [ $XCopyDefault == 1 ]
then
   $BinDir/TWXinputInstall.perl -find
   if [ $? == 1 ]
   then
      cp -a xorg.conf.ORIG $XorgConf
   fi
fi
```

Usually this puts out this error, although I don't think the errors are critical (warnings?):

```
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/TWDrvStartup missing LSB keyword 'required-start'

update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/TWDrvStartup missing LSB keyword 'required-stop'

update-rc.d: warning: TWDrvStartup start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match LSB Default-Start values (2 5)
update-rc.d: warning: TWDrvStartup stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (0 1 3 4 6)
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/kioskadmin/Desktop/twscreen/TwMonitor': File exists
root@kiosk1:/home/kioskadmin/Desktop/twscreen#
```

I also asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/139162/touch-screen-ubuntu-10-04lts) on Super User quite a long time ago, although other than the link to the Ubuntu forums, nothing.  If I recall correctly, no one on the Ubuntu Forum was very helpful beyond pointing me to the same post. It seems "touchscreens" is a specialized topic that not a lot of people know much about.

My questions:

1  Any tips to get this to work correctly?  My major problem seems to be the newer boot process in 10.04.

2  Any alternative calibration software or touchscreen driver that may work or is worth trying? (serial, not USB).

It seems that the the driver is not initiating correctly. The calibration software and control panel do not detect the controller for some reason.  My assumption at the moment is that the init script is not correct, most likely due to changes in Ubuntu's start-up process.

Edit:

It seems I can now run the control panel script correctly, I was having problems with Java, but I just had to execute it differently.  Now I have the problem that the control panel and calibration software cannot detect the touchscreen. Everything runs, but just can't find it,  even though it's connected and it responds if I enable the screen manually.

The error is, "touchscreen 1 is not present".

Comment: wonder how long this will remain unanswered

Comment: ...still no answer

Comment: how do i add a bounty....

Comment: I wish i could extend the bounty as it never was solved... had to move to xp where 3m decided to have a working driver :(.  not idea but couldn't figure this out

Answer (score 1):

On maverick,add this PPA and try

`ppa:utouch-team/utouch`

Comment: interesting... well that has my attention

Comment: well that would be nice but it seems to have support for usb touchscreen only... this one is serial

Answer (score 1):

Please see this to get help with MultiTouch in Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#Community%20Help

Make sure you include the result of lsusb when you ask your question there. Thank you!

However this may not be enough to properly configure your device drivers. I would suggest filing a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `/opt/twscreen/Remove` script.

edit the `/opt/twscreen/TWDrvStartup.ORIG` file and update the `BEGIN INIT INFO` to look like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: TwDriver
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 3 4 6
# Description: Start the MT 7 touch screen driver
### END INIT INFO
```

Run the `/opt/twscreen/Install`

Comment: you might want to use code formatting for commands, scripts and config file content. this improves the readability and avoids serious problems when for example part of the config file is parsed as markup.